# Getting the raw content from pastebin [Java]

Tags: java, http, pastebin

When I try to retrieve the data from a pastebin and convert it to a string. It returns nothing. Just an empty line.

Code:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i="+pasteKey);
    String text = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), 
             StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    System.out.println(text);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have tried using `GET` but got the same result

Comment: Better you should post your solution as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) rather than as an edit to your question.

Comment: As you are aware, please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I was developing with Construct 2. I had to use an external website to bypass some security protocol. I don't remember what it was, but it worked. Here is the website. https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=. Paste your raw url after "url="

I realize I am very late. but if you are still stuck on it, I hope this helps.

Comment: I have already answered my own question in my question a very long time ago (  under EDIT ). I should have put it in a separate post, but thanks anyways.